# Loop on a directory and do some analysis by using shell Script

Tags: shell

Problem Description:

i have a directory with a set of files and these files name saved in table into database called "File_names"
i want to make shell script that loop on the  directory and each time  search if that file name exist in the database or not ,then if no : insert that name into database . else do nothing.

My trail:

```
FILES=/path/*
for f in  $FILES
do
 echo $f
done
```

But $f here contains the path + name i want to be the name only to do smthing like:

```
count = " select count(*) from File_names where name = $f"
```

How can i do this ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: And the DB is Oracle, SQL server...?

Answer (score 2):

I don't find your question very clear; I'll answer the shell part of it as I understand it.

As far as I understand, you want to run a command on each file in a directory. But you're only interested in the base name of the file, i.e., without the directory part.

- Alternative 1

  ```
  for f in /path/*; do
    echo "$(basename "$f")"
  done
  ```
- Alternative 2

  ```
  set -e
  cd /path
  for f in *; do
    echo "$f"
  done
  ```

  `set -e` is so that the script stops if the `cd` command fails. It's usually a good idea to start shell scripts with `set -e`.

Be careful about quoting, in case the file names contain punctuation characters or spacing. This applies to both the shell part and the SQL part: the way you're constructing the query in your question is completely open to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) (think what would happen if someone created a file called `foo; DROP TABLE File_names`).